# how to display posts in a grid layout in codeigniter

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, multiple-columns, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to set grid layout for my blog posts, but i can't achieve it. could someone here to help me.i will put my code in there (for editing purpose).
i am using bootstrap for my view

this is my `index` for my posts page in `application/view/posts/index.php` directory:

```html
<?php foreach($posts as $post) : ?>
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>assets/images/posts/<?php echo $post['post_image']; ?>">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $post['title']; ?></h5>
    <p class="card-text"><?php echo word_limiter($post['body'], 60); ?></p>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('/posts/'.$post['slug']); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">read More</a>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: what is your exact problem or what error u got pls tell?

Comment: i want to display the posts as grid ex: (3 Column)

Comment: are you using bootstrap

Comment: yes man i am using bootsrap

Comment: then you have to set a row and loop with  `<div class="col-md-4">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*View should be like this :*

```
<div class="row">
<?php foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo site_url('assets/images/posts/'.$post['post_image']); ?>" >
             <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $post['title']; ?></h5>
                <p class="card-text"><?php echo word_limiter($post['body'], 60); ?></p>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('posts/'.$post['slug']); ?>" class="btn btn-primary">read More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```